# Xamarin iOS Control Event creating duplicates

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have been trying to create a TouchDown event for my Button in Xamarin for iOS. I have created a simple xib file with 2 buttons in it.

In Visual Studio, the IDE I am currently using, I selected the first button in the xib and in the Events tab in the Properties window, I wrote OnClick and pressed the Add button for the TouchDown event.

This created the event and works as you would expect. The OnClick method in the code behind gets called when the button is pressed.

So naturally I for the second Button I went again to the Events tab and instead of writing the OnClick function again, I selected the OnClick event from the dropdown, expecting the same function to get called.

However, when I press now I get the infamous `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error. This is because in the generated file, a second method was created.

```
[Action ("OnKeyPress")]
[GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
partial void OnKeyPressed ();

[Action ("OnKeyPress")]
[GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
partial void OnKeyPressed (UIKit.UIButton sender);
```

The method with the sender parameter is obviously the correctly generated method which the first button connected to. And the second method is invalid, since it does not contain the sender parameter. My question now is, how can I prevent Visual Studio from creating the corrupted method?

Answer (score 0):

> My question now is, how can I prevent Visual Studio from creating the
>   corrupted method?

I just tested it on my side, and I found after you create a second button:

If you `select the OnClick event from the dropdown`, it will create a second method.

If you `writing the OnClick function again` instead of select the OnClick event from the dropdown, it will not generate a a second method.

So you could choose the write the function name again and create the function in code behind like this:

```
partial void OnClick(UIKit.UIButton sender) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was able to get it to work by just selecting one from the dropdown menu multiple times and removing the old one. It's a tedious process but it worked out. Your process however, definitely makes it easier for the future.

I will open a bug thread on the Visual Studio side.